# Reading from an object javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Have a look

```
console.log(docs);
console.log(docs.key);
console.log(docs.user);
// outputs:
[ { key: 'HunueVwerwbZwesZHxntesDciakecyiJ',
user: 'liam@hogan.re',
createdAt: Mon Mar 17 2014 08:48:30 GMT-0400 (EDT),
_id: 5326ef1ee883062522faa4a8,
__v: 0 } ]
undefined
undefined
```

What's wrong with the way I am trying to access this object?

Comment: You've wrapped it as an array. `docs[0].key` would work.

Comment: That's an array, the object is the `[0]` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docs` is an Array. You can check that like this

```
console.log(Array.isArray(docs));
// true
```

So, you can check the length of the array, like this

```
console.log(docs.length);
// 1
```

Since it has only one element, we can access the first element with the subscript notation, like this

```
console.log(docs[0].key);
console.log(docs[0].user);
```

**Note:** We access the first element with `0`, because JavaScript Arrays start with index 0.

Instead you can drop the object and retain only the array, like this

```
docs = docs[0];
```